# Erro em Haskell Not in scope: data constructor ‘Medicamentos’

Tags: haskell

Boa tarde, como saio desse erro?
Estou tentando incluir um elemento em uma lista de tuplas.

```
    type Nome             = String
    type Quantidade       = Int
    type HorarioProximo   = Int
    type HoraAtual        = Int
    type Horario          = [Int]
    type Medicamento      = (Nome,Quantidade)
    type Medicamentos     = [Medicamento]
    type Prescricao       = (Nome,Horario,HorarioProximo)
    type PlanoMedicamento = [Prescricao] 

    adicionarMedicamento :: Medicamento -> Medicamentos -> Medicamentos 
    adicionarMedicamento (a,b) [] = Medicamentos++[(a,b)]
    adicionarMedicamento (a,b) [(c,d):(e,f)] | (a == c)  = (a,b+d)
                                         | otherwise = (c:d):(adicionarMedicamento (a,b) [(e,f)])
```

Alguém por favor?

Answer (score 1):

Na sua função `adicionarMedicamento :: Medicamento -> Medicamentos -> Medicamentos` na linha `adicionarMedicamento (a,b) [] = Medicamentos++[(a,b)]` você **refere-se ao segundo parâmetro da função**, inicialmente, como `[]`, porém, na sequência, ao juntar o Medicamento `(a,b)` recebido a lista de Medicamentos, você **refere-se ao segundo parâmetro da função**, como `Medicamentos` e isso causa o erro:

```
    Data constructor not in scope: Medicamentos :: [(Nome, Quantidade)]
   |
12 | adicionarMedicamento (a,b) [] = Medicamentos++[(a,b)]
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Pois o compilador conhece **o segundo parâmetro da função** como `[]`, para corrigir use o mesmo nome de parâmetro definido inicialmente.

Lendo o seu código, entendo que você deseja adicionar um medicamento a lista de medicamentos, caso esse medicamento não esteja contido na lista. Porém, caso o medicamento já esteja contido na lista, você deseja aumentar a quantidade do medicamento. Caso base nisso, proponho o seguinte código:

```
type Nome             = String
type Quantidade       = Int
type HorarioProximo   = Int
type HoraAtual        = Int
type Horario          = [Int]
type Medicamento      = (Nome,Quantidade)
type Medicamentos     = [Medicamento]
type Prescricao       = (Nome,Horario,HorarioProximo)
type PlanoMedicamento = [Prescricao] 

adicionarMedicamento :: Medicamento -> Medicamentos -> Medicamentos 
adicionarMedicamento (a,b) c |elem (fst (a,b)) [fst c | c <- c] == False = c++[(a,b)]
                             |otherwise = aumentarDose (a,b) c

aumentarDose :: Medicamento -> Medicamentos -> Medicamentos
aumentarDose m ms |fst (head ms) == fst m = [(fst m, snd m + snd (head ms))]++tail ms
                  |otherwise = [head ms]++(aumentarDose m (tail ms))
```